# Windows Server 2012 - PHP Database Connection Issue

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I am having troubles connecting to a test Database which I set up recently.

My PHP Version is 5.6. I have downloaded the SQL Driver and extracted the relevant Files into the ext/ directory - screenshot:

[image]

I also included the filenames as extension in the php.ini file - screenshot:

[image]

Actually I don't even know if my connection would be successfull because I am getting following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\db.php on line 12
```

My PHP Code:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// Server in diesem Format: <computer>\<instance name> oder
// <server>,<port>, falls nicht der Standardport verwendet wird

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$serverName = "SERVERNAME\MSSQLSRV";

$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'RiverDatabase', "UID"=>"USERNAME", "PWD"=>"PASSWORD");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);


if($conn) {
     "Connection established.<br />";
}else {
     "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT: SQLSRV Extension seems to get regocnized now**

But now I get the following error message:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben ) )
```

Which leads me to a Website that suggests to download the SQL Driver, which I already did.

I have also activated the php_pdo_odbc.dll - thought thats what the error message is trying to tell me.

Comment: Are you, by any chance,using WAMP?

Comment: Load the nts version of your extension, since the PHP installation should be non-thread-safe on windows, too. Check phpinfo() if the extensions are loaded correctly. If you are using IIS, install PHP Manager for IIS and manage your PHP configuration from there.

Comment: No I am not using WAMP.

Do I have to remove the ts extensions from the ext/ directory and from the php ini and replace it with the ts version, or can i keep "both"

Comment: @noa-dev you can keep the files (even though they're useless). PHP only loads files listed in your `php.ini` file.